# How can I import gl-matrix in a ReactJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have just tried using ReactJS recently, and I came across and played with [this project](https://github.com/chriz001/Reacteroids) which import JS modules via syntax like this:

`import Particle from './Particle'`

I wished to port the project to use `gl-matrix` as a practice to get familiar myself with this framework, but now I'm unsure how I should proceed. Should I be able to `require` as suggested on [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gl-matrix), or there is some way to `import` `gl-matrix`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can just `require` it like usual:

```
var glm = require('gl-matrix');
```

Of course, make sure you've run

```
npm install --save gl-matrix
```

or have `gl-matrix` as a dependency in your `package.json`. If that doesn't work, try just importing the script directly in your `index.html`:

```
<script src="gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

Then you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining how `import X from '.<filename>'` work? Is this a ReactJS specific thing? Should I be able to change some code so that I could import "gl-matrix" this way as well?

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with React or the `import` syntax, but here is a [reference from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). I suspect you could do `import "gl-matrix";` or `import * from "gl-matrix";`... try it out and let me know what works.

Comment: I do know that with `require` or `import`, prefixing the module name with `./` will search the current directory for the file, while just specifying the name of a module will load it from your installed `node_modules`